# How to write an AssertTags test in SimpleTest with regex?

Tags: regex, unit-testing, cakephp, simpletest

I wish to test a function that will generate `lorem ipsum` text, but it does so within html tags. So I cant know in advance the textual content, but i know the html structure. That is what I want to test. And maybe that the length of the texts are within certain limits.
So what I am wondering is if the assertTags can do this in a way paraphrased bellow:

```
Result = "<p>Some text</p>";
Expected = array( 
   '<p' ,
   'regex',
   '/p'
);
assertTags(resutl, expected)
```

I am using SimpleTest with CakePHP, but I think it should be a general question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$expected = array(
    '<p',
    'preg:/[A-Za-z\.\s\,]+/',
    '/p'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Extend the SimpleExpectation class and then use your new Expectation class in the assert statement

see: http://www.lastcraft.com/expectation_documentation.php#extending

the example given is for validating an IP address but should be applicable to your problem:

```
class ValidIp extends SimpleExpectation {

  function test($ip) {
    return (ip2long($ip) != -1);
  }

  function testMessage($ip) {
    return "Address [$ip] should be a valid IP address";
  }
}
```

then in your test

```
$this->assert(new ValidIp(),$server->getIp());
```